# Initialize 3D lookup table (LUT) via preprocessor?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, c-preprocessor, lookup-tables

I am using a lookup table to convert raw pixel data between color spaces and coding variants. This is the definition of my LUT:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char data[3];
} rgb;

rgb LUTYUVTORGB[256][256][256];
```

It is initialized like this:

```
// loop through all possible values
for (int in_1 = 0; in_1 < 256; in_1++) {
    for (int in_2 = 0; in_2 < 256; in_2++) {
        for (int in_3 = 0; in_3 < 256; in_3++) {

            int out_1, out_2, out_3;

            // LUT YUV -> RGB
            // convert to rgb (http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/colorspace/yuv/)
            out_1 = (int)(in_1 + 1.4075 * (in_3 - 128));
            out_2 = (int)(in_1 - 0.3455 * (in_2 - 128) - (0.7169 * (in_3 - 128)));
            out_3 = (int)(in_1 + 1.7790 * (in_2 - 128));

            // clamp values
            if (out_1 < 0) { out_1 = 0; } else if (out_1 > 255) { out_1 = 255; }
            if (out_2 < 0) { out_2 = 0; } else if (out_2 > 255) { out_2 = 255; }
            if (out_3 < 0) { out_3 = 0; } else if (out_3 > 255) { out_3 = 255; }

            // set values in LUT
            LUTYUVTORGB[in_1][in_2][in_3].data[0] = (unsigned char)out_1;
            LUTYUVTORGB[in_1][in_2][in_3].data[1] = (unsigned char)out_2;
            LUTYUVTORGB[in_1][in_2][in_3].data[2] = (unsigned char)out_3;
        }
    }
}
```

The LUT is then applied to copy the raw pixel data to a QImage():

```
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        xpos = (y*w + x); // don't calculate 3 times
        buff[x * 3 + 0] = psImage->comps[0].data[xpos];
        buff[x * 3 + 1] = psImage->comps[1].data[xpos];
        buff[x * 3 + 2] = psImage->comps[2].data[xpos];
    }
    memcpy(image.scanLine(y), buff, bytes_per_line);
}
```

The values of the LUT are static, and have to be initialized every time the programm starts. Is there any way to initialize it via the preprocessor? Or would it be recommendable to save it in a file?

EDIT: The conversion is used in a time critical video application where every frame has to be processed individually.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Why do you need such a large (64MiB) lookup table in the first place? The conversion is quite simple so that you can do it on the fly.

Comment: My recommendation is save it in a file with some structure.

Comment: @Leon I should have mentioned that the conversion is used in a time critical video application where every frame has to be processed individually.

Comment: @Cherkesgiller Tural what structure would you suggest?

Comment: Are you sure you will benefit from such a large LUT table? It won't fit in the cache, so performance will not be too good. Have you tested it compared to simply calculating the value each time?

Comment: It's usual to embed lookup tables directly in program code by having the data beforehand or generating by the build system and insert as C array in a header file. This way they would be on stack and on a short way to load. But yours is just too big, most compilers won't support such a big stack size, so you have to get them dynamically. Because I/O is very expensive, you should check, how much faster it's to create the table on the fly.

Comment: @ddriver I have noticed considerable improvements in speed (around 30-40%) using the lut. Other color spaces need more computation time, therefore I think going with the lut(s) really is the best option.

Answer (score -1):

I have created one dimensional array for this table, it is convenient to save and load such array.  I think using this array in runtime wont decrease performance. But I didn't test it for performance differences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LUTSIZE 0x1000000

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char data[3];
} rgb;

rgb *LUT;

inline int LUT_index(int in_1, int in_2, int in_3) {
    return in_1 * 0x10000 + in_2 * 0x100 + in_3 * 0x1;
}

inline rgb LUT_value(int in_1, int in_2, int in_3) {
    return LUT[LUT_index(in_1,in_2,in_3)];
}

void save(rgb *LUT, char* fileName) {

    FILE* file = fopen(fileName,"wb");
    int index;

    for (int in_1 = 0; in_1 < 256; in_1++) {
        for (int in_2 = 0; in_2 < 256; in_2++) {
            for (int in_3 = 0; in_3 < 256; in_3++) {

                int out_1, out_2, out_3;

                // LUT YUV -> RGB
                // convert to rgb (http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/colorspace/yuv/)
                out_1 = (int)(in_1 + 1.4075 * (in_3 - 128));
                out_2 = (int)(in_1 - 0.3455 * (in_2 - 128) - (0.7169 * (in_3 - 128)));
                out_3 = (int)(in_1 + 1.7790 * (in_2 - 128));

                // clamp values
                if (out_1 < 0) { out_1 = 0; } else if (out_1 > 255) { out_1 = 255; }
                if (out_2 < 0) { out_2 = 0; } else if (out_2 > 255) { out_2 = 255; }
                if (out_3 < 0) { out_3 = 0; } else if (out_3 > 255) { out_3 = 255; }

                index = LUT_index(in_1,in_2,in_3);

                // set values in LUT
                LUT[index].data[0] = (unsigned char)out_1;
                LUT[index].data[1] = (unsigned char)out_2;
                LUT[index].data[2] = (unsigned char)out_3;
            }
        }
    }

    fwrite((void*)LUT, sizeof(rgb),LUTSIZE,file);
    fclose(file);
}

void read(rgb *LUT, char* fileName) {
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fread((void*)LUT,sizeof(rgb),LUTSIZE,file);
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LUT = (rgb*)malloc(LUTSIZE * sizeof(rgb));
    save(LUT, "LUT_data");
    rgb testValue = LUT_value(5,3,7);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", testValue.data[0], testValue.data[1], testValue.data[2]);

    read(LUT, "LUT_data");
    testValue = LUT_value(5,3,7);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", testValue.data[0], testValue.data[1], testValue.data[2]);

    free(LUT);
}
```

Comment: A multidimensional array is already continuous in memory, you don't really need to rework it to make it "serializable".

Comment: Thank you @ddriver, I have tested both arrays perform same.